# How do I create bookmarks in DOCX output using XSL:FO

Tags: xsl-fo

I am creating 2 versions of output for a document. PDF and DOCX. The PDF is complete and the table of contents and bookmarks are working as expected. I am not able to get the bookmarks to work in the DOCX output however. My PDF also uses hyperlinks to link to the page being referenced. I am hoping to get that working as well, but would at least like a valid page number to be displayed.

Table of Contents

```
<fo:basic-link internal-destination="employeePage">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">EMPLOYEE PAGE
        - <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="employeePage"/>
    </fo:inline>
</fo:basic-link>
```

Bookmark on the Employee Page

```
<fo:inline id="employeePage"/>
```

Again, that works for me in creating PDF output but not DOCX. The rest of my DOCX output is fine, just not the bookmarks/table of contents. (Page references will be dynamic.)

In the table of contents in my DOCX output, I get, "EMPLOYEE PAGE - 0" but no hyperlink.

I have also tried the following where I get, "EMPLOYEE PAGE - 0" in the DOCX, and for the page number on the hard copy when actually printed, it says, "Error! Bookmark not defined."

Table of Contents

```
<fo:inline font-weight="bold">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">EMPLOYEE PAGE - 
        <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{generate-id(.)}"/>
    </fo:inline>
</fo:inline>
```

Bookmark on the Employee Page

```
<fo:inline id="{generate-id(.)}"/>
```

If the hyperlink portion of it should be a separate question, that's fine. Any help getting the page numbers to appear correctly would be great.

Comment: Why would you expect DOCX (which has no pages) to understand what page a link points to? And you must also post what product you are using to convert XSL FO to DOCX because you are not just "opening" the XSL FO file in Word.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to "DOCX (which has no pages)". Perhaps I was unclear on how I described the page linking from the table of contents issue. I have a footer that displays the current page successfully, so I was under the impression I could link to 'pages' from the table of contents. To your second point, I am using a third-party app that utilizes Antenna House for the XSL FO conversion to DOCX and PDF.

Comment: if the xsl fo through processing to pdf works, then i suspect you should ask the vendor of the product converting that same xsl fo to docx why their software is not replicating this.